# JavaScript getElementsById from variable

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

i would like to ask you how can i get elements by id from variable in JavaScript. For example i have in JavaScript variable which contains html source code and i would like to get elements from this variable.

For example:

```
var html = "<html><body><div id='test'>Hi</div> ... lot of code ... <div id='test'>Hi</div><div id='test'>Hi</div> ... lot of code ... </body></html>";

var get = html.getElementsById("test");
```

But it's not working

Thank you so much for any help

Comment: An `id` should be unique

Comment: `document.getElementById` not `html.getElementsById`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```
var html = "<html><body><div id='test'>Hi</div> ... lot of code ... <div id='test'>Hi</div><div id='test'>Hi</div> ... lot of code ... </body></html>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');


var get = doc.getElementsById("test");
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do what you are doing. You have a few problems.

1. `getElementById` is singular, not plural (`getElementsById`). This is because in properly formatted html, every id must be unique. Browsers allow it to slip by, but it is one element only
2. `getElementById()` is a method on the **DOM** not on a **string** as you are doing above.

There are three ways that I can think of to do this:

You could try creating a regex to do it, but it would be messy. You would need to find every occurrence of `id\s+=\"'+myVar+\"' and then find the element surrounding it. Very messy, but doable.

Better is to load it into a browser and then do `document.getElementById()`

Even simpler is to use jquery

```
$(html).find('#test');
```